# How to access response value outside onResponse method in android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-volley

I am working on a android project. I got the response from google api and parsed the json. But i want to return the value outside of onResponse method which seems to be impossible for me now. Below is my code, I have already seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839985/how-to-return-value-from-onresponse-in-volley-methods) here. But i want this value outside of this async method. Is it possible to access this value.

**UPDATE** - I have updated my code for more details. This is my full activity class. You can see what i want to achieve. Please help me how i can access value returned by Volley `onResponse` in method `get_time_to_travel`,  inside method `parseJson`. This is really killing me now. My first android project and i am stuck here from last two days.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private List<UserData> userData;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    String origin, mode = "driving";
    private String API = "APIKey";
    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    RequestQueue requestQueue1;
    String url = "https://url/users";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                origin = String.valueOf(lat)+","+String.valueOf(lng);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
            }
            return;
        }
        else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
        }


        getData();

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, userData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void getData(){
        userData = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        parseJson(response);
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void parseJson(JSONArray response){
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject users = response.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = ("id: "+users.getString("id"));
                String name = ("Name: "+users.getString("name"));
                String username = ("Username: "+users.getString("username"));
                String email = ("Email: "+users.getString("email"));
                String address = parseAddress(users);
                String destination = parseCoordinates(users);
                String company = parseCompany(users);
                String phone = ("Phone: "+users.getString("phone"));
                String website = ("Website: "+users.getString("website"));
                String eta = get_time_to_travel(origin, destination, API, mode);

                UserData udata = new UserData(id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company,eta);
                userData.add(udata);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private String parseAddress(JSONObject users) {
        JSONObject completeAdd = null;
        String address = null;
        try {
            completeAdd = users.getJSONObject("address");
            String street = completeAdd.getString("street");
            String suite = completeAdd.getString("suite");
            String city = completeAdd.getString("city");
            String zipcode = completeAdd.getString("zipcode");
            address = ("Address :" + street + ", " + suite + ", " + city + ", " + zipcode);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return address;
    }

    private String parseCoordinates(JSONObject users) {
        JSONObject completeAdd = null;
        String destination = null;
        try {
            completeAdd = users.getJSONObject("address");
            JSONObject coordinates = completeAdd.getJSONObject("geo");
            String latitude = coordinates.getString("lat");
            String longitude = coordinates.getString("lng");
            destination = latitude + "," + longitude;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return destination;
    }

    private String parseCompany(JSONObject users) {
        JSONObject companyDetail = null;
        String company = null;
        try {
            companyDetail = users.getJSONObject("company");
            String company_name = companyDetail.getString("name");
            String catchPhrase = companyDetail.getString("catchPhrase");
            String bs = companyDetail.getString("bs");
            company = ("Company: " + company_name + ", " + catchPhrase + ", " + bs);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return company;
    }


    private String get_time_to_travel(String origin, String destination, String API, String mode){
        requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String eta = null;
        String google_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+origin+"&destinations="
                +destination+"s&mode="+mode+"&language=fr-FR&key="+API;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, google_api, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        eta = parseGoogleData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                    }
                }

        );
        requestQueue1.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return eta;
    }

    private String parseGoogleData(JSONObject response) {
        String estimated_time_arrival = null;
        try {
            JSONArray rows = response.getJSONArray("rows");

            JSONObject elements = rows.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray elementsArr = elements.getJSONArray("elements");

            JSONObject durationObj = elementsArr.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject durationData = durationObj.getJSONObject("duration");
            estimated_time_arrival = durationData.getString("text");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return estimated_time_arrival;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you want to access ?

Comment: I am caaling this method inside my main activity and i want this value to be accessed in main activity.

Comment: Why not doing code inside `onResponse` method which you want to do after executing `onResponse` method ?

Comment: and to access data outside you need to create a custom listener using interface

Comment: because i am getting userdata from other api and i have to show userdata and this value on same card. Also can you tell me how to create custom listener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134338/discussion-between--k-and-sinscary).

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `OnCreate()` of activity, remove these 2 lines

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, userData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in `getData()` remove this line

```
userData = new ArrayList<>();
```

put them in `parseJson()` as below:

```
private void parseJson(JSONArray response){
    try {

        if(userData==null){
            userData = new ArrayList<>();
        }else{
            userData.clear();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject users = response.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = ("id: "+users.getString("id"));
            String name = ("Name: "+users.getString("name"));
            String username = ("Username: "+users.getString("username"));
            String email = ("Email: "+users.getString("email"));
            String address = parseAddress(users);
            String destination = parseCoordinates(users);
            String company = parseCompany(users);
            String phone = ("Phone: "+users.getString("phone"));
            String website = ("Website: "+users.getString("website"));
            String eta = get_time_to_travel(origin, destination, API, mode);

            UserData udata = new UserData(id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company,eta);
            userData.add(udata);
        }

        if(adapter == null){
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, userData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }else{
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this way, when json call finish, `parseJson()` is called.
and after parsing the array into `userData` the adapter is initialized or notified.

**EDIT:**

Well, this is not the best sol. but it's just something from the top of my head
little nasty/dirty. i don't know but i think it will do the job

1- you don't have to reinit the queue every time, so in `get_time_to_travel()` put that line out of the method:

```
requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

add `final int index` param to the method and make it `void`:

```
private void get_time_to_travel(String origin, String destination, String API, String mode, final int index){...
```

make `onResponse()` in the method like this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    eta = parseGoogleData(response);
    userData.get(index).setEta(eta);//add this setter to your data object if not exist.
}
```

**remove** `return eta;`

init udata with empty string as `eta` for now:

```
UserData udata = new UserData(id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company,"");
userData.add(udata);
```

modify the call to `get_time_to_travel()` in `parseJson()` as below:

```
get_time_to_travel(origin, destination, API, mode, i);
```

when `get_time_to_travel()` is called at `onResponse()` the object will be modified to hold the `eta` value retrieved from the API

this is nasty, sometimes the `adapter` might be notified before all calls to **google api** is completed. so this is just to show you how to make it

**Edit2**
a workaround for this is 
init userData object with label "Loading..." for eta

```
UserData udata = new UserData(id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company,"Loading...");
```

and notify the adapter at end of `onResponse()` of `get_time_to_travel()`:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    eta = parseGoogleData(response);
    userData.get(index).setEta(eta);//add this setter to your data object if not exist.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: You think is there any need of change in `get_time_to_travel` method. Coz i tried that but still not getting the `eta` value.

Comment: @Sinscary i have updated the answer to make sure it works find, let me check the `get_time_to_travel ` and post update if i can answer that.

Comment: @Sinscary yes, you need to change it, this is another call to web service and response is returned through a callback, so assign it to variable in parseJson() is not correct cuz the response might be not there yet.

Comment: This is what killing me. Please tell me a way i can achieve this.

Comment: @Sinscary check the **edit**, it's not final not tested, just to show you some guidance.

Comment: i will give it a try, but still i am confused. Maybe coz i am not that much proficient in java and android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134378/discussion-between-yazan-and-sinscary).

Answer (score 2):

Async task is doing work on other thread. So if you want to access any variable out side that method, you need to wait until the task get completed. Otherwise the variable will be null.
eg: on on response method

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            res=response;
            anyMethodtopassVar(DataType data);
        }
```

Comment: you can pass value from on response method I think. using methods. so after completing the task that method will be called. @Sinscary

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the result of `parseJson` inside `onResponse`?
Change the return type of parseJson to `UserData`, call `return userDate;` inside try block and `return null;` in catch block. This will help you catch the result of parseJson from where you are calling it. 
Let me know if I did not understand your question properly.

Comment: No i am getting the parseJson result properly. I am not getting `eta` value from `get_time_to_travel`.

Comment: @Sinscary in that case your code seems to be okay, are you sure you are parsing the json correctly? Make sure by checking the log in Android Studio for any Json Exceptions, or using Log.d for logging eta[0] inside get_time_to_travel method.

Comment: Yes json is parsed correctly. Please once check `get_time_to_travel` method and i am calling it in `jsonParse`. This is where the problem is.

Comment: Hi @Priyam, So you think is there a way to access response from onResponse in method `get_time_to_travel`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new     Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            res=response;
            callback.onSuccess(res);
        }
    }...
}}

public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

Now inside your mainactivity you can do like this.

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
getString(new VolleyCallback(){
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String res){
         ... //do something
     }
});
```

}

Comment: Tried that and also this answer is copied. I think stackoverflow is not about copy pasting answers.

Comment: i have used this one some months before and it has worked for me.I copied this code from my project because i didn't found the link now.

Comment: If you carefully read my code, you will find that i have already done that

Comment: then have you tried using bus library it can also be used to solve your problem.