# How to access childs and sub childs of json file from server in android recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-studio, arraylist, server

I want to access array child and sub child elements from json file that is stored on server,and show them in recyclerview i tried lot of ways but none othem working for me because i don't have knowledge about this library

```
    {
  "category1": {
    "subcategory1": {
      "products": [
        {
          "title": "Air Fresheners",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Cloth Detergent",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Milk",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "subcategory2": {
      "products": [
        {
          "title": "Air Fresheners",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Cloth Detergent",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Milk",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "category2": {
    "subcategory1": {
      "products": [
        {
          "title": "Air Fresheners",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Cloth Detergent",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Milk",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "subcategory2": {
      "products": [
        {
          "title": "Air Fresheners",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Cloth Detergent",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        },
        {
          "title": "Milk",
          "image": "https://ludobets.in/atma_nirbhar/my_private_secure_icons/secure_home_icons/ic_apps_scan.png"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

i tried many way without having knowledge of them but none of that working for me.
It gives error as shown below

```
of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

my code is

```
private void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObjectRoot = response.getJSONObject("category1");
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSub = jsonObjectRoot.getJSONObject("subcategory1");
                    JSONArray jsonArrayForSub = jsonObjectSub.getJSONArray("products");
                    JSONObject eachObjectInArray = jsonArrayForSub.getJSONObject(i);

                    Note note = new Note();
                    note.setTitle(eachObjectInArray.getString("title"));
                    note.setImage(eachObjectInArray.getString("image"));

                    noteList.add(note);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: If my knowledge of JSON serves me correct, subcategory is not a JSON array, but instead it is an object, the JSON Array in this instance is product

Comment: the code above is just an example of my code while the json above is actually i want to use for my purpose

Comment: yes, and in your code, you are saying `jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("subcategory")` but that is incorrect, because subcategory (in your json) is not an array

Comment: thank you, please help me with this and i search a lot for this but found nothing

Comment: try reading thru this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928314/how-to-access-response-value-outside-onresponse-method-in-android

Answer (score 0):

use retrofit instead to fetch the json from the server and convert into the modle class structure list, here is the reference
link : https://square.github.io/retrofit/